# How to get ETH contract balance with Ethers.js

Tags: ether, contract-invocation, balances, ethers.js

I am trying to get the ETH balance of a contract:

```js
const balance = await contract.getBalance();
```

but it fails:

```
TypeError: contract.getBalance is not a function
```

What I do wrong and how to fix the error?

Answer (score 32):

*getBalance* is a function of the Ether.js blockchain provider object, it is used this way :

```
const balance = await provider.getBalance("address");
```

Note that you can use `contract.address` to obtain the address of the contract instance.

Comment: what chain is this balance for?

Comment: Late to this. The chain depends on the provider. When creating the provider you specify the network (through the RPC URL or otherwise).

Answer (score 8):

In the context of testing a contract with Hard Hat:

```
const { ethers, waffle} = require("hardhat");

const provider = waffle.provider;
const balanceInWei = await provider.getBalance(contract.address);
```

where contract is a deployed contract instance.

Answer (score 4):

You also can use:

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
const balance = await provider.getBalance("address");
```

Comment: This actually seems wrong as using ethers.getDefaultProvider provides the default provider an not the one in use.  You really should be calling ethers.provider

Answer (score 1):

```
const address1 = "0x042523DB4F3Effc33d2742022B2490258494f8B3"
const bal = provider.getBalance(address1) //balance in wei
const balance = ethers.formatEther(bal) // wei balance convert to eth balance
console.log(balance)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Wagmi and React :

```
  const provider = useProvider()
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState<BigNumber>()

  useEffect(() => {
    const run = async () => {
      setBalance(await provider.getBalance(address))
    }
    run()
  }, [provider, address])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Your Contract Name and Your Solidity File name are not the same because i had get this error before

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/89746)

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: contract.getBalance is not a function

You can try:

```
npm install @ethersproject/units
```

Then import it:

```
import { formatUnits } from "@ethersproject/units";
```

And then:

```
const balance = await provider.getBalance(address);

const ethbalance = formatUnits(balance, "ether");
```