# ethers.js get balance returns 0

Tags: ethers.js

I am trying to get the balanace of an address, the address I am trying to get is the pair address when liquidity is added.

I have tried using provider.getbalance shown in this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/88243/79469).

This is my code

```
factory.on('PairCreated', async (token0, token1, pairAddress) => {
  const balance = await provider.getBalance(pairAddress);
  console.log(`
    ${token0}
    ${token1}
    ${pairAddress}
    ${balance}
  `);
```

This returns

```
0x56Ca8Df9F4A602e449265931ff2dA8210F53F230
0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c
0x148818634356E6af1d4727A26b8181D7b892aA8c
0
```

When I check the balance of 0x148818634356E6af1d4727A26b8181D7b892aA8c on bsc scan I get 3 different tokens with different balances, but when I try through ethers it returns 0.

How could I get the tokens/balances of pairAddress (0x148818634356E6af1d4727A26b8181D7b892aA8c) using ethers.js?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You're reading the ETH balance, not the ERC-20 balance. The former is the native currency of Ethereum, the latter is a smart contract build on top.

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying @PaulRazvanBerg, makes sense. Do you know how I can get the ERC-20 and balances of those for an address? Thanks

Comment: It depends. This is sort of like asking where you can find the physical address of a restaurant. I could find it on Google Maps, on Yelp, or in private conversation with a friend on Signal.

Comment: I suggest you go through the [Hardhat tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/) before continuing with your development.